# MicroProfile and Wildfly Swarm time to rebuild in development environment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, microservices, wildfly-swarm, microprofile

We are working in a micro service project using MicroProfile and Wildfly Swarm, and we are having a problem in the development enviroment with the build time, it's taking over 3 minutes and every changes that we do in the project we have to rebuild the project to test, each time that we rebuild the project the Swarm install all fractions and start again, this proccess is taking much time in the project's development.

Anyone is having this same problem? What can i do to avoid the rebuild(install the fractions and start) i want just publish the code or how to do a hotdeploy with Swarm and MicroProfile?

Comment: Three minutes seems like a long build time. How big is your project?

Comment: Hot deploy in Swarm/Thorntail is currently not possible. But if you do minor changes, you can use the JVM's hot code swap. If you use IntelliJ: connect to your app with a debugger, recompile the modified classes and you'll be asked if you want to replace them. I believe Eclipse has similar capabilities. You can also give Thorntail Runner a try (https://thorntail.io/posts/thorntail-runner/). It will still require a restart of your app but should be faster than the "normal" flow